# Poisson distributions where the mean given does not match the time interval considered in the analysis

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I've been revisiting Poisson distributions and I'm creating a question from scratch.

My main point is: when the time interval changes (in the case below from 5 to 8 hours), is it simply a matter of calculating another mean (proportionally)? I'll write, below the question, my answers for it.

> Let's say that my daughter usually cries at night once every 5 hours.
> That said:
>
> a) What is the probability that she cries once in that
> time frame?
>
> Let's consider now an 8-hour block of sleep time.
>
> b) If she wakes me up zero or once, I'll be fine the next day. What is
> the probability that I'm fine the next day?
>
> c) If she wakes me up five times or more, I'll skip work that day. What is the probability that that happens?

**My answers for the exercises are (not sure these are correct):**

a) $\displaystyle P(X=1) = \frac{1^1 \cdot e^{-1}}{1!} \approx 0.368$

b) We need now to find another mean for the 8-hour block, which will be $1.6$ baby cries per hour

$\displaystyle P(X \leq 1) = P(0) + P(1) \approx 0.525$

c) Using the mean found in the exercise above,

$\displaystyle 1 - P(X \leq 4) \approx 0.0237$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: On a side note: Is there reason to believe that the number of times a baby cries during the night would follow a Poisson distribution? It could be interesting to look at actual data (over many nights) and see if the Poisson approximates that data reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. In general, the probability distribution of $n$ cries in time $t$ is given by

$$P(N(t)=n) = \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda t}$$

where $\lambda$ is the average number of cries per unit time. In your case, you chose $\lambda=1$ and your unit time is $5$ hours.

The reasoning behind this is that you are observing a [Poisson point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process). The Wikipedia page contains all useful interpretations of this process.